# install library using a .sh script; the default location won't work

Tags: shell, fortran

I'm trying to compile the library at this site http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/prob/prob.html

You can find the library by searching for the text prob.f90

The library comes with a shell script to compile it, called prob.sh

When I use sudo bash prob.sh at the terminal (I am using OSX Lion) I get told that the directory ~/bin//f90split doesn't exist.

If I open prob.sh in a text editor it looks like the shell script is trying to compile the library to ~/bin/$ARCH/f90split

Is it ok for me to simply change this line of the shell script to /usr/lib/ and install the library there instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can edit the script as you suggest.  Personally I wouldn't compile the library directly to `/usr/lib` in a first attempt, I'd compile to some other directory which I could easily clear out if things go awry.